# How do I tell sound manager 2 to only play some audio files?

Tags: soundmanager2

I use the page payer demo for one of my projects and I want to play some audio files with mediaelements and some with soudmanager. It seems that sound manager plays for all of them or actually both are played with some echo some time.

Thank you

Update:
when I add demo/page-player/script/page-player.js to my page the custom button I implemented to play with mediaelements gets the time under it like: 0:03 / 1:04

Here is the meadiaelement code I use

```
$('.btn-play').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var player;

        if($('#Player').length === 0){
            $('body').append('<audio id="Player" class="hide" src="'+$(this).attr('href')+'">');
        }
        player = new MediaElementPlayer('#Player');
        player.pause();
        player.setSrc($(this).attr('href'));

        if($(this).hasClass('play-pause')){
            $(this).removeClass('play-pause');
            player.pause();
        }else{
            $('.btn-play').removeClass('play-pause');
            $(this).addClass('play-pause');
            player.play();
        }
    });
```

The weird part us that the mediaelement player is added at the bottom of the page but maybe soudmanager is triggered somehow and adds the .controll and .timing divs

here is the html button that should not be modified by sound manager.

```
<a href="assets/files/theatre-performance/AnthonyAccardiDemo.mp3" class="btn btn-color-1  btn-play">Audio demo<span class="wsnw">&nbsp;<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
```

**Note:
I wonder if soundmanager hooks into every link that has an mp3 or some media format in it**

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: updated, hope it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution was to add "exclude" class to the button that triggers mediaelement player. Seems like the code in the demo (demo/page-player/script/page-player.js) uses canPlayLink method to get all the playable elements.

You can also edit demo/page-player/script/page-player.js self.hasClass(o,'exclude') to self.hasClass(o,'your_exclude_class')